# What is the best way to force the type of instance variables in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, types, instance-variables

Lets say I want to create a `class Person` in ruby, with variables `@name` and `@age`. What is the best way to ensure that variables have specific class: `@name` is a String and `@age` is Integer?

It is not obvious since ruby uses "duck-typing". I assume I could use `raise` clause in `initialize` method but I would like to know what is the best practice?

For example in Java I could declare variables types, and assing them by passing to the constructor arguments with the same type.

```
class Person {  
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "best", it's really a matter of opinion.  What's wrong with using `@name = name.to_s` and `@age = age.to_i` in the constructor, for example?  You'd probably want to check for reasonable values on age as well...

Comment: You could set each instance variable using a setter only, checking the class in the setter: `class Person; def name=(name); <raise exception> unless name.is_a?(String); @name = name; end; def initialize(name); self.name = name; end; end`. Then write (say) `person = Person.new("Bugsy")`. `person.name =  4` would raise an exception. This is not fail-safe, however, as one may always invoke `person.instance_variable_set(:@name, 4)`.

Comment: You may come up with a hack to do that, but it does against what Ruby is about. Ruby encourages duck typing. It tries to go away from classes. Variables do not have type.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you want to enforce a specific type? Just because you are used to doing so from working with Java? Or do you try to solve a specific problem/issue? I ask because it is uncommon in Ruby to enforce types and solution to specific issues depending on the problem.

Comment: @spickermann I think it is good practice to keep everything strictly and tidy, to avoid unexpected errors, some time later.

Comment: @KaRolthas Seems like a dynamically typed language like Ruby isn't the best choice then...

Answer (score 2):

[TypeError](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/TypeError.html) is built-in and usually used. `Kernel#raise` is fine too.

```
class Person
  def initialize(age)
    raise TypeError, "age should be an Integer" unless age.is_a?(Integer)
    @age = age 
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> “If a method is written with a specific input type in mind, such as an Integer, we can use Ruby's standardized conversion methods to ensure that we are dealing with the type the code expects. If we want to provide maximum leeway in input, we can use explicit conversion methods like #to_i. If we want to provide a little flexibility while ensuring that client code isn't blatantly mis-using our method, we can use an implicit conversion such as #to_int.”

Excerpt From: Avdi Grimm. “Confident Ruby”.